# Some of my dataframe values include dictionaries, while others contain values. How do I remove the dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', {'$numberDouble': 'NaN'}],
                   'B': ['c', {'$numberDouble': 'NaN'}, 'd'],
                   'C': [{'$numberDouble': 'NaN'},'e','f']})
```

How do I replace all the {'$numberDouble': 'NaN'} to null values?

I've tried the following but there were no changes:

```
df.replace('$numberDouble', np.nan)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use applymap with an if/else statement

`df.applymap(lambda x: np.nan if isinstance(x, dict) else x)`

```
     A    B    C
0    a    c  NaN
1    b  NaN    e
2  NaN    d    f
```

Comment: Good approach! Another possibility using `mask` would be: `df.mask(df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict)))`.